# Making a 3D Live Wallpaper with Blender only

Tags: export, video, scene

What I want to do is create 3D scene animation in Blender then turn it into live wallpaper on my laptop.

I did consider Wallpaper Engine but the question is - Can I use the 3D scene where the path of recording camera took place in Blender then import the file to Wallpaper Engine to make it a live Wallpaper?

Example:
[Exo Zombies Carrier Lobby Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBWUA8hSwHE)

Comment: Hi. If you have an answer add it in the answer box below instead of in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh thank you Stranger! I'm very new to Blender and Stackexchange forums

Answer (score -2):

You can record it in Blender then save it as video file to be used in Wallpaper Engine.